AzCopy not working within Docker container image
I've been attempting to put AzCopy into a Docker image, I've built the image successfully but it seems to fail on run with
exec /usr/local/bin/azcopy: no such file or directory
Please find my Dockerfile below:
ARG ALPINE_VERSION=3.19

FROM alpine:$ALPINE_VERSION

ARG AZCOPY_VERSION=10

RUN apk add --no-cache curl \
   && echo "AZCOPY_VERSION is set to ${AZCOPY_VERSION}" \
   && curl -L "https://aka.ms/downloadazcopy-v${AZCOPY_VERSION}-linux" -o azcopy.tgz \
   && tar -xzf azcopy.tgz --strip-components=1 \
   && ls -l \
   && mv azcopy /usr/local/bin/azcopy \
   && ls -l /usr/local/bin/azcopy \
   && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/azcopy \
   && rm -rf azcopy.tgz

   CMD ["azcopy"]

Command used to build:
docker build --no-cache -t myazcopy --build-arg AZCOPY_VERSION=10 .
docker run --name myazcopy-test -it myazcopy
Any help would be hugely appreciated, thank you

What kind of thing is azcopy once you've downloaded it?  Have you checked that you have the right language interpreter, if it's not in a compiled language, or the right C shared libraries, if it's an ELF binary?
